# Can external harddrives be permanently mounted for routine backing up?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, drobo, continuous-operation

I have a couple external hard drives I use for backing up data.  The way I use them is simply keep them stored until needed, and then I plug them in, let them get recognized and then backup data...  I then remove the drive as per protocol and store again.

But I want to start doing auto-backups of some files (using [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) or other programs, scripts, etc...  So the question is, if I plug in and mount (on Ubuntu) an external hard drive (a [SeaGate FreeAgent Pro MSeries](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/freeagent/), for example) will this be OK, i.e., will there be an adverse effects to the drive by running it continuously?

Ideally I would get something like a [Drobo setup](http://drobo.com/), because these are built for this type of system...  But they are expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drive will receive no worse effects from being connected all the time than your internal hard drives do. Standard wear-and-tear.

But for backups, if they're connected directly to your machine all the time there is a *potential* danger if you have something happen that damages the entire machine (think strong power spike or virus attack - the latter less of an issue given you're Ubuntu) and may cause you do loose both the original data *and* your backup.

Comment: This is kinda what I thought...  I have several machines on a network, all very secure by a pfSense firewall.  Plus, the machine on which the drive will be mounted is Ubuntu, so this should be fine, like you say.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes** You may connect your external hard-disk as long as you want.
>
> One **Big Disadvantage** would be , it
>   will no longer be a safe Back-up since
>   a Simple virus infection could infect
>   your Back ups as well .
>
> A **Workaround** to this problem could be
>   to download and install WinRaR, and
>   convert evreything you want to back-up
>   into rar file. Most virus attacks dont
>   aim at rar files.

And uh forgot to mention that power fluctuation for some reason adversely affects all plugged in external storage media. My 3 pen-drives became corrupted :(

Comment: Good points.  I would have the power running the a UPC anyway, so this wouldn't be a factor.